# Row numbers in Python based on row values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks as follows

```
+----------------------------+
| name | value | col | date  |
|------|-------|-----|-------|
| a    | play  | 0   | 05-01 |
| a    | sub   | 1   | 05-02 |
| a    | play  | 1   | 05-03 |
| a    | stm   | 1   | 05-04 |
| b    | stm   | 0   | 05-01 |
| b    | stm   | 0   | 05-02 |
| b    | sub   | 1   | 05-03 |
| b    | play  | 1   | 05-04 |
|------|-------|-----|-------|
```

the value column has three values `play, stm, sub`. the `col` column value changes from 0 to 1 when it encounters the first `sub` row for a `name`.

I want to convert this data frame to

```
+---------------------------------+
| name | value | col | date  | rn |
|------|-------|-----|-------|----|
| a    | play  | 0   | 05-01 | -1 |
| a    | sub   | 1   | 05-02 |  0 |
| a    | play  | 1   | 05-03 |  1 |
| a    | stm   | 1   | 05-04 |  2 |
| b    | stm   | 0   | 05-01 | -2 |
| b    | stm   | 0   | 05-02 | -1 |
| b    | sub   | 1   | 05-03 |  0 |
| b    | play  | 1   | 05-04 |  1 |
|------|-------|-----|-------|----|
```

the first row for a particular `name` get `rn=0` when `value=col`. The `rn` value decreases as we go up and increases as we go down in the table for the same `name`.

Comment: whats happen if no `sub` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is create mask by compare `sub` value with [`DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) and then by mask select [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with default ascending or if no match by descending ordering:

```
mask = df['value'].eq('sub').groupby(df['name']).cumsum().ne(0)

g = df.groupby(['name', mask])
df['new'] = np.where(mask, g.cumcount(), g.cumcount(ascending=False).add(1).mul(-1))
print (df)
  name value  col   date  new
0    a  play    0  05-01   -1
1    a   sub    1  05-02    0
2    a  play    1  05-03    1
3    a   stm    1  05-04    2
4    b   stm    0  05-01   -2
5    b   stm    0  05-02   -1
6    b   sub    1  05-03    0
7    b  play    1  05-04    1
```

If no value `sub` per group then output is:

```
print (df)
  name value  col   date  new
0    a  play    0  05-01   -4
1    a   stm    1  05-02   -3 <- no value sub
2    a  play    1  05-03   -2
3    a   stm    1  05-04   -1
4    b   stm    0  05-01   -2
5    b   stm    0  05-02   -1
6    b   sub    1  05-03    0
7    b  play    1  05-04    1
```

Comment: `mask = df['col'].astype(bool)` ?

Comment: Mmm I think so , OP said  *the value column has three values play, stm, sub. the col column value changes from 0 to 1 when it encounters the first sub row for a name*

Comment: @ansev - ya, unclear, so rather more general solution ;)

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, We can use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`Series.sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) after [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) `rn` values where `'value'` is **`sub`**

```
new_df = (df.assign(rn = df.groupby('name').cumcount())
            .assign(rn = lambda x: x['rn'].sub(x['name'].map(x[x['value'].eq('sub')]
                                                        .set_index('name')['rn']))))
print(new_df)
  name value  col   date  rn
0    a  play    0  05-01  -1
1    a   sub    1  05-02   0
2    a  play    1  05-03   1
3    a   stm    1  05-04   2
4    b   stm    0  05-01  -2
5    b   stm    0  05-02  -1
6    b   sub    1  05-03   0
7    b  play    1  05-04   1
```

**Alternative**

```
df2 = df.assign(rn = df.groupby('name').cumcount())
df2['rn'] -= df2.merge(df2.loc[df2['value'].eq('sub'),
                               ['name', 'rn']],
                       on='name')['rn_y']
print(df2)

  name value  col   date  rn
0    a  play    0  05-01  -1
1    a   sub    1  05-02   0
2    a  play    1  05-03   1
3    a   stm    1  05-04   2
4    b   stm    0  05-01  -2
5    b   stm    0  05-02  -1
6    b   sub    1  05-03   0
7    b  play    1  05-04   1
```